# Jersey Client 2.19 doesn't throw exceptions on bad status code

Tags: java, exception, jax-rs, jersey-client

I'm building a `Rest Client` using `jersey-client 2.19`:

```
public ReleaseEntity createRelease(ReleaseEntity newRelease, int workspaceId) {

    Releases wrapper = new Releases();
    wrapper.setData(Arrays.asList(newRelease));

    WebTarget target = client.target(urlPrefix)
            .path(AgmUrls.getReleasesUrl(workspaceId));

    wrapper = target
            .request()
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .post(Entity.entity(wrapper, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .readEntity(Releases.class);

    return wrapper.getData().get(0); 
}
```

The client is initialized in the `constructor`

```
this.client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
```

The problem is that, in case of bad response the `post` call does not throw an exception, neither `explicit` nor `runtime`.

Should I do this manually, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The framework should not throw an exception. The user should handle the response however they see fit. This is the same with any client. The `Response` object will contain all the context you need to handle the response however you see fit.

So what you *should* do is get the `Response` first

```
Response response = target
         .request()
         .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
         .post(Entity.entity(wrapper, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
```

Then you can check the status

```
int status = response.getStatus();
```

Then handle the status

```
if (status == 200) {
    wrapper = response.readEntity(Releases.class);
    ...
} else { 
    handleOtherStatus();   
}
```

If you do not get the `Response` first, then you have no idea what the actual problem is, as `readEntity(...)` will fail (as there it's not the body you are expecting), and throw a different exception. With the `Response` at least you have some context if you want to tell the user what actual problem is.

Comment: That's the way a would've done it. But I thought maybe the client had some advanced `API` to handle this. For example, implementing `JAX-RS` by myself I had these exceptions thrown on bad response statuses.

Comment: I don't see why it _should_ have any sort of built in functionality like this. Status error codes are not programming errors. There are infinite ways to handle error status codes. Who's the client API to say what should happen for each error code. That's the way I see it.

Answer (score 5):

This question is quite dated, but better prevent others to repeat the same mistake...

Instead of

```
result = target
            .request()
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .post(Entity.entity(input, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .readEntity(Releases.class);
```

which has `post(entity)` return a `Response` on which `readEntity` is called, better use overloaded `post(entity, responseType)` which will throw `WebApplicationException` on Error-Statuscodes.

```
// throws runtime exception derived from WebApplicationException
// on error-statuscodes
result = target
            .request()
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .post(Entity.entity(input, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON), Releases.class);
```

Every http method in JAX-RS has such overloaded methods for reading either Responses or representation objects. Reading representation objects is highly advised to consume potential response bodies in any case.

```
// consumes response as string and guarantees to close the http call.
// A no-arg delete(); would be a potential leak!
target.request().delete(String.class);
```

Unfortunately, when response-headers must be read, it is still required to read `Response` instead of the representation objects.